# Writing content of an array to a textbox using foreach loop C#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, foreach

So, I wanna know how to write the entire content of an array to a textbox by using a foreach loop in C#. My code currently looks like this:

I generate a series of random numbers which are stored in the array:

```
int[] iData;
```

Now I want to write the stored data in this array to a textbox by using the foreach loop like this:

```
        foreach (int myInt in iData)
        {
            txtListing.Text = myInt.ToString();
        }
```

This will only write the last generated number in the array to the textbox, but my question is how do I write all of them to the tekstbox.

I only know, how to do this with a listbox and a forLoop. But is there any way this can be done with a textbox and a foreach loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [`AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) method instead:

```
foreach (int myInt in iData)
{
    txtListing.AppendText(myInt.ToString());
}
```

Another option is to join the elements together as a string:

```
textListing.Text = string.Join(string.Empty, iData);
```

...or if you want another delimiter:

```
textListing.Text = string.Join(", ", iData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the strings successively.

```
foreach (int myInt in iData)
        {
            txtListing.Text += myInt.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Because .NET (and, indeed Java) strings are immutable, every time you perform a string concatenation, you create a new string instance to put the concatenated string into. In a loop this means allocating dozens of temporary string variables which the garbage collector then has to dispose of. Use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is writing the content of each item in turn to the text property, which is leaving the last entry in place as there's no further changes.

You're probably best off using String.Join to concatenate all the values together and write to the Text property.

i.e.

```
String.Join(", ", iData.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

As Fredrik pointed out,

```
String.Join(", ", iData);
```

Is neater.

Comment: `string.Join` takes an `object[]` and takes care of the conversion, calling LINQ methods is a bit overkill for the task.

Answer (score 2):

The low tech approach:

```
        foreach (int myInt in iData)
        {
            txtListing.Text = txtListing.Text + "; " + myInt.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach (int myInt in iData)
{
    txtListing.Text += myInt.ToString();
}
```

This should append each value to the `.Text` property, rather than overwrite it.

Comment: @Massif: True, there are much better ways to do this.  Sometimes I find myself thinking those are questions for another day, though.  Maybe I'm just too much of a cynic :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Set

```
 txtListting.MultiLine = true
```

2) Change code:

```
 txtListing.Text += myInt.ToString() + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove null values of the array using linq:

```
Array = Array.where(x => !string.isNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Convert to string:

```
String result = string.join("",Array);
```

Write to textbox:

```
Textbox.text=result.tostring();
```

Didn´t use foreach but may solve your problem